# File Upload using MEAN stack to AWS EC2 fail

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I have a form where I fill input alongwith files and send it as JSON using angularjs to nodejs server and store it into mongodb. In the localhost, its working fine. I am able to upload files from my browser and store it into local storage. And then, storing the path of the file into mongodb.

But when I do the same after deploying in AWS EC2, the files are not coming. Though, mongodb and http.post() of angularjs is working fine as am able to sign up into my website and the userprofile is stored successfully into the mongodb and later can log in too. Where is the problem, I cant figure it out?
Thanks in advance. If any snippets needed, comment below.

Client-side: (in angular js)

```
scotchApp.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function($http){
    this.post = function(uploadUrl, data1, data2){
        var fd = new FormData();
        for(var key in data1)
            fd.append(key, data1[key]);
        fd.append("data2", JSON.stringify(data2));
        $http.post('/upload', fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        });
    }
}])
```

Server-side: (Nodejs server)

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var property = JSON.parse(req.body.data2);
    var imgPaths = new Array(req.files.file1.path.substring(6),req.files.file2.path.substring(6),req.files.file3.path.substring(6),req.files.file4.path.substring(6),req.files.file5.path.substring(6),req.files.file6.path.substring(6));
    property["imgPaths"] = imgPaths;
    var id = req.body._id;
    var longi = "-";
    var lati = "-";
    var geocoderProvider = 'opencage';
    var httpAdapter = 'https';
    var extra = {
        apiKey: '4996751802785975c32ce8819418c376', 
        formatter: null 
    };
    var geocoder = require('node-geocoder')(geocoderProvider, httpAdapter, extra);
    geocoder.geocode(property.location, function(err, resp) {
        try {
            lati = resp[0].latitude.toString();
            longi = resp[0].longitude.toString();
        }
        catch (excp) {
           console.log(excp);
        }
        finally {
        property['latitude'] = lati ;
        property['longitude'] = longi ;
        var propertyformObj = new PropertiesProfileModel(property);
        propertyformObj.save(function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send('error');
                }
                else {
                    res.send('ok');
                }
        })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code please? (Client-side upload code, receiving controller action code.)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is the express server process might not have permission to write to a folder. Run chmod 777  foldername to grant all access to all users for that folder where you want to store the file. Then test if it works. If it does then you know it was a permission issue. P.S. These steps are only to debug the problem. Grant correct permissions to folder. Do not leave the permissions as 777 as that can be a serious security issue.